# Model return me "_required" error on field that it's not empty Cake php 3.8

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I use cakephp 3.8 and I want to save my entity in my sessions table but, the Model return to me an error that I don't understand, because as you can see on the screenshot, my "is_active" field is not empty, her value is to true.

[image]

And this is my validation rules in my model :

```
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->scalar('name')
        ->maxLength('name', 255)
        ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('name');

    $validator
        ->boolean('is_active')
        ->requirePresence('is_active', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('is_active');

    return $validator;
}
```

And this is my code :

```
$session = $this->Sessions->newEntity(['session_state_id' => 'OPENED', 'section_id' => $section_id, 'is_active' => true]);
$this->Sessions->patchEntity($session, $this->getRequest()->getData());
$this->Sessions->save($session);
```

Thanks you very much for your help,

Loic

Comment: Can you show us all the validation rules associated with `is_active` from your model code?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, I have updated my post

Comment: How do we know that this field was actually part of the patched data? What does the code that creates the entity look like? ps, please try to avoid posting code as images - thanks!

Comment: @ndm Because i'm put this directly when I declare my entity, I've edited my post with code. As you can see my "is_active" property is part of my entity

Comment: It's part of your entity, but not necessarily part of your patched data, ie it's probably not present in `$this->getRequest()->getData()`? That would make sense if it actually shouldn't be possible to patch that in from user data, but it would cause the problem that you're showing.

Comment: @ndm No, because in my $this->getRequest()->getData() I don't have any "is_active" field, and my debug was made after the patch entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are patching twice above, the error gets triggered by your 2nd one, "patchEntity()". Fix your code, I would say to not patch twice, or include the field in your data, or adjust your validation rules.

In general, do always patch only once per type "create" vs "edit".
So above, you should be doing:

```php
$data = $this->getRequest()->getData();
$data['is_active'] = true; // add fields on top for the same marshalling.
...

$session = $this->Sessions->newEntity($data);
$result = $this->Sessions->save($session);
```

Alternative for create actions (when needing an entity for the form building):

```php
$session = $this->Sessions->newEmptyEntity(); // this one doesn't patch.
$ession->is_active = true; // Add fields directly (no validation)

$data = $this->getRequest()->getData();
$data['...'] = ... // If needed for validation

$session = $this->Sessions->patchEntity($session, $data);
$result = $this->Sessions->save($session);
```

The reason here in your case is:
You are setting "on create" rule for validation.
But no matter how often you patch, it is still not saved, so the same validation rule gets triggered again and again.